# magento use xml layout update to insert text into text-box

Tags: xml, magento, layout

I wanted to see if it was possible to use Custom Layout Update XML to input specific text into a text-box. For example, if the cms page contains a form to submit your email address to sign up for a mailing list, could I use the Custom Layout Update to populate the field with "example@example.com"?

I've been able to use the addText action method to add text to the page. But, I have not been able to pin-point it to get it to go into the text-box.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of Layout Update XML and Javascript should set you right here.  Just use the `addText` method to add some javascript to the page that sets the text.  For example, the following will set the text of the search box on the Magento homepage to `Neat`.

```
<action method="addText">
    <text>![CDATA[
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
                var f = $('search');
                if(!f)
                {
                    return
                }
                f.value = 'Neat';
            });
        </script>
    ]]></text>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks! You pushed me in the right direction. I ended up using... document.getElementById('search') .value = 'Neat';